# How to know which simulator is used in cocotb testbench?

Tags: python, verilog, icarus, cocotb, verilator

To test my Verilog design I'm using two differents simulators : [Icarus](https://github.com/steveicarus/iverilog) and [Verilator](https://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilator). It's work, but there are some variations between them.

For example, I can't read module parameter with verilator, but Icarus works.

Is there a way to know which simulator is in use in python testfile ?

I would like to write something like that :

```py
        if SIM == 'icarus':
            self.PULSE_PER_NS = int(dut.PULSE_PER_NS)
            self.DEBOUNCE_PER_NS = int(dut.DEBOUNCE_PER_NS)
        else:
            self.PULSE_PER_NS = 4096 
            self.DEBOUNCE_PER_NS = 16777216
```

To be able to manage both simulator and compare them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The running simulator name (as a string) can be determined using [`cocotb.SIM_NAME`](https://docs.cocotb.org/en/stable/library_reference.html#cocotb.SIM_NAME). If cocotb was not loaded from a simulator, it returns `None`.